# How to have only the current sub-menu get an active class instead of all of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click on a submenu item in my menu, all the submenu items get the `main-nav-active` class, but I want only to have the parent and the current submenu item to have the `main-nav-active` class.

Here is my menu:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.menu .main-nav li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('main-nav-active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu float-right pr-4 pt-4 mt-1">
   <ul class="main-nav">
      <li>
         <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="position-relative">
         <a href="/zonwering">Zonwering</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
            <span><a href="/zonwering/terrasscherm">- Terrasscherm</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/terrassoverkapping">- Terrasoverkapping</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/screens">- Screens</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/rolluiken">- Rolluiken</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/markiezen">- Markiezen</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/uitvalscherm">- Uitvalscherm</a></span>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/terrasoverkapping">Terrasoverkapping</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/over-ons">Over ons</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/offerte-aanvragen">Offerte aanvragen</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class AUX in each SPAN.

```
$(document).on('click', '.aux', function({
    $(this).addClass('main-nav-active'); // or child, you change
    $(this).parent('.dropdown-content').addClass('main-nav-active'); 
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
$('#subMenu').click(function() {
   $('.menu .main-nav li a').addClass('main-nav-active');
   $('.menu .main-nav li .dropdown-content a').removeClass('main-nav-active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you select the link, just save that and then find the relevant parent element.  Add the class to both

```js
$(function() {
  var $link = $('.menu .main-nav li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]');
  var $ddlParent = $link.parents('.dropdown-content');
  $link.add($ddlParent).addClass('main-nav-active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`a[href^="..."]` will select **everything** that starts with the provided string.  So, the translated `a[href^="/zonwering"]` correctly assigned the class to all elements that started with */zonwering*.

> [attr^=value]
>   Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

---

This may not be the most elegant of solutions, but I wanted to run with the code that you have already tried to use and extend it for your purposes...

For the ease of using the snippet tool here on StackOverflow, I just made a global variable to represent the `location.pathname` as `pathname`.

The first line `$('.menu .main-nav li a[href="' + pathname + '"]').addClass('main-nav-active2');` -- you know what page you're on, you don't need to get fancy to select it.

The second part tests if there is a parent element, and then trims the pathname string to get the parent anchor link URL.  And then selects it accordingly.

```js
var pathname = '/zonwering/terrassoverkapping';

$(function(){
  // assign class to the link for the current page...
  
  $('.menu .main-nav li a[href="' + pathname + '"]').addClass('main-nav-active');
  
  // check to see if there is a "parent" link to the current page ...
  var path = pathname.split('/');
  if( path.length > 2 ){
  // in this example path = [ '', 'zonwering', 'terrassoverkapping' ]
  
    /* with the structure we know that if the path array is longer than 2, then it has a parent path */
    // create the parent path...
    var parentPath = '/' + path[1];
    // same as the previous assignment, but this time with the parent path instead of the current page
    $('.menu .main-nav li a[href="' + parentPath + '"]').addClass('main-nav-active');
  }
});
```

```css
a.main-nav-active{ color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu float-right pr-4 pt-4 mt-1">
   <ul class="main-nav">
      <li>
         <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="position-relative">
         <a href="/zonwering">Zonwering</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
            <span><a href="/zonwering/terrasscherm">- Terrasscherm</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/terrassoverkapping">- Terrasoverkapping</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/screens">- Screens</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/rolluiken">- Rolluiken</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/markiezen">- Markiezen</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/uitvalscherm">- Uitvalscherm</a></span>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/terrasoverkapping">Terrasoverkapping</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/over-ons">Over ons</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/offerte-aanvragen">Offerte aanvragen</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This could potentially be optimized into ...

```js
var pathname = '/zonwering/terrassoverkapping';

$(function() {
    var path = pathname.split('/');
    var pathStr = '';
    for( var i=path.length; i>0; i-- ){
      pathStr = path.slice(0,i).join('/');
      $('.menu .main-nav li a[href="' + pathStr + '"]').addClass('main-nav-active');
    }
});
```

```css
a.main-nav-active{ color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu float-right pr-4 pt-4 mt-1">
   <ul class="main-nav">
      <li>
         <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="position-relative">
         <a href="/zonwering">Zonwering</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
            <span><a href="/zonwering/terrasscherm">- Terrasscherm</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/terrassoverkapping">- Terrasoverkapping</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/screens">- Screens</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/rolluiken">- Rolluiken</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/markiezen">- Markiezen</a></span>
            <span><a href="/zonwering/uitvalscherm">- Uitvalscherm</a></span>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/terrasoverkapping">Terrasoverkapping</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/over-ons">Over ons</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/offerte-aanvragen">Offerte aanvragen</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Doug, all the submenu items still get the class `main-nav-active`

Comment: I included your original code -- I can strip it out entirely.  I just wanted to show the difference between the two.  In my first example, the `.main-nav-active2` should display what I assume are your desired results

Comment: @JariRengeling -- updated and provided an additional solution.